# How to redirect to store from ionic v4 app?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I started working on an **ionic v4** project [my .ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1t5S.png) and [my .html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNSms.png) I need to know **how to redirect to a specific app on the play store or app store**, when a button is clicked.

I already checked a few links on google but none of the methods listed seem to work with me. I tried using the **cordova Market plugin**, but the button does not redirect me to the play store.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please show examples of what you've already tried and where specifically you're facing a problem.

Comment: @Tom I have edited the question with images from my project, kindly check them.

Comment: Please don't use images of code, instead copy it into code tags in your question.